# One-liner to make video DVD-player-compatible

Tags: video, dvd, video-conversion

I have lots of movies in `avi` format. Some of them are not compatible with my DVD-player.

Is there a one-liner for `mencoder` or `ffmpeg` - to do just minimal conversion to make the videos DVD-player-compatible?

I don't want to lose any quality or do any transcoding. There's a DeVeDe but - it doesn't do just minimal conversions.

Comment: Does your DVD player play *some* AVI files but not others, or does it only play standard DVDs?

Comment: It does! I think it's a pretty standard dvd-player - and the problem is relevant for many people.

Comment: Could you please clarify? Does it play some AVI files or does it only play DVDs?

Comment: @Adobe - the point is that if it only plays regular DVDs, it will require DVD-formatted streams of PAL/NTSC MPEG-2 video and precisely nothing else. If it plays some AVI files but not others, maybe the others can be tweaked without reprocessing.

Comment: I appreciate Your help. It plays both - for  sure - DVDs and some AVIs. For some other AVIs it says - "the format is not supported". It could also play mp3. So overall - it's really just basic modern dvd-player ("it's a Sony" BTW).

Comment: Can you get two AVIs, one that plays and one that doesn't, and then run [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) on those two? Add some screenshots to the question and then we can see which codecs we need. Get back to me with @slhck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found soulution:

```
mencoder inputFile -ovc xvid -xvidencopts pass=1:threads=4 -oac mp3lame -lameopts vbr=3 -o outputFile.avi
```

(subsitute your's number of threads, or if you have a single thread discard ":threads=4")

I tried it for both avi file I coundn't play before, and mkv file. Both plays well in my dvd-player (Sony) after the above transcoding. Both files got a little bit fatter after transcoding:

- avi: 1.5G -> 1.6G
- mkv: 1.4G -> 2.1G

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend handbrake.

But a warning. Be prepared to lose a good amount of quality.  This is inevitable due to, well, the laws of nature. Short of retouching each frame manually, this will apply til the heat death of the universe.

Comment: How will Handbrake help if you don't even know which formats are compatible and which not? Handbrake does not even output AVI containers anymore, and no MPEG-2 either (if that's what the DVD player needs).